# Send generated html to a php script

Tags: php, html, send

I already have this script

```
<FORM method="POST" name="ajax" action="#">  
<INPUT type="submit" class="env_buttn" value="<?php echo "Generate"; ?>"            
ONCLICK="gen_data()">
<div id="data_gen"> 
    // generated html to be sent to check.php
 </div>
 </FORM>
```

What I want to do is send the generated html in the div to another php script check.php .
I've thought of adding another button but I don't know how to do it properly. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what you want to do in check.php? Like, do you want to do ajax stuff and get a response immediately, or just send data off, or do some kind of redirection?

Comment: Are you using javascript to submit the form? And why `<?php echo "Generate"; ?>` not just `"Generate"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get html from inside an element do this in javascript:

```
var html = document.getElementById('data_gen').innerHTML
```

So that's part of your question answered at least... What do you want to do with the html?

Assuming you want to do ajax style stuff... just add this function to an onclick event for a button:

```
function event_calls_this()
{
    var html = document.getElementById('data_gen').innerHTML;
    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url       : 'blah/check.php',
        data      : {the_html:html},
        type      : 'POST',
        success   : function(data)
        {
            //do what you need to do with the response
        }
    }
}
```

One question that springs to mind is: What are you actually trying to do? Does the user somehow fill in the div? If yes then how? I'm pretty certain that changing your strategy would yield a more elegant solution but I'm unsure of the specifics... so, if this doesn't solve your problem, can you give us some background info?

Comment: Firstly , Im not the one who created the script so Idont know too much about how it does work.
My goal is to creat a php script that check links generated between the divs and show the broken one's, this script will only be available for administrator.
now my problem is how to send the generated links to the php script.
hop its clear enough now

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<div>` with `<textarea>` if you want it to be submitted with the form:

```
<form method="post" name="ajax" action="#">
    <input type="submit" class="env_buttn" value="Generate" onclick="gen_data()">
    <textarea name="data_gen">
    </textarea>
</form>
```